# How to fix Python 2.7 and Numpy syntax error in tmp directory

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I am installing my setup.py dependency file on a Ubuntu 16 instance. When I run the setup.py file below is the error I am getting.

```
File "/tmp/easy_install-z7cdA1/pandas-1.0.3/setup.py", line 42
  f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}"
```

The problem happening is that file is in a tmp directory which I am not able to debug. From the error I am guessing it is some numpy version issue with Python 2.7. Any help fixing this issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` [removed support for Python 2.7](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/install.html#plan-for-dropping-python-2-7) starting from version 0.25.0.

The most up-to-date version you can install for 2.7 is

```
pip install pandas==0.24.2
```

---

You can see the error is because there's an f-string, which is a python 3.6 feature. `pd.__version__ == '1.0.3'` officially supports Python 3.6.1 and above, 3.7, and 3.8.

Comment: Ok but how do i debug it? where to change the python version?

Comment: @error2007s you can't really just change python versions like you can library versions. 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 are all totally different installations. Likely a lot of things will break going from 2.7 to 3.6 so I wouldn't suggest just doing that. You can install a different python version in parallel and then re-install all of the libraries, or you need to uninstall that version of pandas and follow the code above to install that specific version.

Comment: So above command fixed that error but new one showed up File "/tmp/easy_install-NyN2F2/django-formtools-2.2/setup.py", line 83
  file=sys.stderr)

Comment: @error2007s Again that's an issue with a version that is too current. https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html. You can see that 2.2 dropped support for Python 2, you'll likely need to use a 2.1 version.

Comment: @error2007s if you are programming for your own personal reasons, and not at the mercy of some company that **requires** you to stick with 2.7 for compatibility reasons, I strongly suggest you bite the bullet now and upgrade to a newer python version, anything 3.6 and above. As you can see many libraries have dropped support for 2.7 and that trend will only continue.

Comment: There was a AWS EC2 instance that was on a autoscaling group running that old version 5 days back that instance refreshed and everything went berserk and none of the reports are now working. I am trying to break fix and make those reports run for time being untill the whole stack is updated to new python version :) lol